# OTRS change customer_user table by MySQL query and update frontend data visualization

Tags: otrs

I execute a query directly in the MySQL database to update the customers users. The query result was successful but in the frontend I can't visualize this.

PRODUCT = OTRS

VERSION = 5.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed delete the application cache.

Is necesary find the script called **otrs.Console.pl** that in my case is located 
in **/opt/otrs/bin/otrs.Console.pl**.

For execute this script and delete the application cache you can type:

```
perl otrs.Console.pl Maint::Cache::Delete
```

It solved the issue described